# Cómo puedo hacer una consulta anidada de 3 colecciones en mongodb?

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb

Tengo el siguiente enunciado:

> Listado de los votos obtenidos por todos los candidatos con el nombre
> del partido político al que pertenecen ordenados de mayor a menor de
> forma general por todas más mesas y también por una mesa en
> específica.

En la colección *candidato* se encuentra la llave foránea de *partido_político* y en la colección *resultado* se encuentra el numero de votos y la llave foránea *candidato*.

A continuación muestro el código que estoy usando.

```
$lookup.
{
  from: 'candidatos',
  localField: 'id.$id',
  foreignField: '_id',
  as: 'result'
}
```

Con este obtengo la información que guarda la colección resultados.

Luego si quiero hacer una segunda consulta con `lookup`

```
{
  
  from: 'partidos',
  localField: 'id.$id',
  foreignField: 'nombre',
  as: 'result2'
}
```

Me sigue arrojando la información que arrojó con el primer `lookup`.

Answer (score 0):

Después de revisar el enunciado y sin conocer la estructura completa de tu BD se me ocurre la siguiente consulta:

```
db.resultado.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "candidato",
      "localField": "candidato_id",
      "foreignField": "id",
      "as": "candidato"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$candidato"
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "partido_politico",
      "localField": "candidato.partido_politico_id",
      "foreignField": "id",
      "as": "partido"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$partido"
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "votos": -1
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "candidato": "$candidato.nombre",
      "partido": "$partido.nombre",
      "votos": 1
    }
  }
])
```

Explicacion de cada etapa (stage):

- En la primera etapa empleados `lookup` para obtener los registros cuya llave foránea (`candidato_id`) en la colección resultados coincida con la llame primaria (`id`) de la colección candidatos
- En la segunda etapa empleamos `$unwind` para deconstruir un campo de matriz y convertirlo en un objeto `{key: value}` para utilizarlo en la siguiente etapa.
- En la tercera etapa empleamos lookup para obtener los registros cuya llave primaria (`id`) en la coleccion partido_politico coincida con la propiedad "partido_politico_id" en el resultado de la segunda etapa.
- En la cuarta etapa empleamos `$sort` para ordenar en base a la cantidad de votos de mayor a menor
- En la quinta etapa empleamos `$project` para definir los campos a mostrar como resultado final de nuestra consulta:

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000005"),
    "candidato": "Pedro",
    "partido": "Partido Independiente",
    "votos": 260
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000004"),
    "candidato": "Ramon",
    "partido": "PRD",
    "votos": 150
  }
]
```

Te dejo un pequeño [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/v8VeKLHU4bO) para que lo revises!